# SSL invalid certificate, may need to cross-certify

Tags: java, ssl, lotus-domino

We have an WebService and provide WSDL to our customers. All customers (there are hundreds) have no problem with our service except one who is using Lotus Notes. When their code trying to connect to our service the issue is thrown back. Here is a log.

I tried to import certificate to Notes JVM (cacerts). Did not help. I tried to disable veritifcation of certificate - did not help as well.

Certificate is GlobalSign

Lotus Notes 9.x. I'm using Java Agent to test WSDL.

Any idea what I have to do?

```
Error connecting to 'api.mywebiste.com' on port '443', SSL invalid certificate, may need to cross-certify.
    at lotus.domino.axis.InternalFault.makeFault(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.axis.client.Call.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.axis.client.Call.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.axis.client.Call.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.axis.client.Call.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.websvc.client.Call.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.e_conomic.EconomicWebServiceSoapStub.connect(EconomicWebServiceSoapStub.java:9032)
    at JavaAgent.NotesMain(JavaAgent.java:20)
    at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: Error connecting to 'api.mywebiste.com' on port '443', SSL invalid certificate, may need to cross-certify.
    at lotus.domino.axis.transport.http.NotesSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: did you try http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd8forum.nsf/4b9931b774db788c85256bf0006b5e6d/82d1e426bb1025688525746c004480c2?OpenDocument ?  i'm assuming you already went through all the google results for this error message?

Comment: Hi, yes, I did. I tried to import certificate and no luck yet. but I agree with you, it must be something related to certificates only. I will continue to look in that side.

Comment: Which certificate are you importing, and what file are you importing it to?  Also, do you require client authentication?

Comment: Notes 8.x or 9.x? Also how is the consumer made in Notes? Agent? Java?

Comment: @warrenDew: GlobalSign

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty: I'm using Notes 9.x. I imported WSDL to Web Consumer (Java) and then used it in Java Agent.

Comment: How is the agent run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the main error is this.

> SSL invalid certificate, may need to cross-certify.

In order for Notes to correctly recognise the SSL certificate you also need to ensure that the whole SSL chain is imported as well. On top of this it has to be cross certified with your organisations certificate (or the users personal certificate).

The following details how to do this for the server for R9.

https://serverfault.com/questions/505273/java-certificateexception-in-domino-9-when-trying-to-access-https-url/515189#515189

It should be somewhat similar process for the local client. You open the personal NAB and go to the advanced->certificates view.

Comment: thanks, it helped.
got another issue after this one (on same place in code)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25746046/web-service-consumer-thrown-faultcode-http-www-lotus-com-domino-ws-http

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is related but there is an [issue with Notes9 supporting SHA-2](http://www.mcpressonline.com/commentary/in-the-wheelhouse-ibm-we-have-an-ssl-problem.html).

There is a workaround for Windows based servers. [Here is IBM's post on the matter.](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ndseforum.nsf/xpTopicThread.xsp?documentId=0BBA1D75D92075FC85257D3B006FABB8)