# Web Service Consumer thrown faultCode: {http://www.lotus.com/domino/ws/}HTTP

Tags: java, ssl, lotus-domino

after [SSL invalid certificate, may need to cross-certify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25727441/ssl-invalid-certificate-may-need-to-cross-certify) has been fixed another issue appears and I'm stuck even more now.

Could someone give me at least idea what is wrong :)

```
{code}
WebServiceEngineFault
 faultCode: {http://www.lotus.com/domino/ws/}HTTP
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: (0) null
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {}string: 

(0) null
    at lotus.domino.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.readFromSocket(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.axis.client.Call.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.axis.client.Call.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.axis.client.Call.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.axis.client.Call.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.websvc.client.Call.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.e_conomic.EconomicWebServiceSoapStub.connect(EconomicWebServiceSoapStub.java:9032)
    at JavaAgent.NotesMain(JavaAgent.java:20)
    at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
{code}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Domino issue.

**Forum discussion**

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd85forum.nsf/5f27803bba85d8e285256bf10054620d/fe67ea61d2ac56a8ca25788e0010a92e?OpenDocument

**Issue description**

https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO59433

**Local fix**

Using:

```
<xs:element name="data" type="xs:base64Binary"/>
```

Instead of:

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="data" nillable="true"
type="xs:base64Binary"/>
```

Appears to prevent the problem.